# Cricket-like sound from headphones microphone

Tags: sound, microphone, headphones

I have issues with my headphone's microphone, it records a crickety-like sound and it's very annoying. Don't know how I can describe it better.

Any ideeas what it can be and how it can be fixed?

Issue is Linux-based, KDE Neon (18.04-based) and Ubuntu 20.04 have the same issue.
Tested on Windows 10, on same laptop, no issue.

Headphones: https://www.pcgarage.ro/casti-gaming/redragon/scylla-black/
The headphones, come with a 2x3.5mm TRS Jacks, but I connect them using a single 2 to 1 Jack adapter (don't know how to properly translate the adapter).

Laptop: https://www.lenovo.com/gb/en/laptops/legion-laptops/legion-y-series/Lenovo-Legion-Y7000-2019/p/88GMY501215

Comment: It might help to add some information on the type of microphone/connection.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I added some more info, is it ok? Thank you.